# Volume control not shown in menu bar even though enabled in Preferences

Tags: menu-bar, sound-volume

The *volume control* is enabled in *Settings | Sound Effects*

[image]

but it is not actually showing ?

[image]

Is there some other setting required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the non scientific method: disabling and re-enabling the *show volume in menu bar* .. and that worked.